# using chrome cannot download a hyperlink to a 7zip

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I use asp.net upload to upload a 7zip on the server. I am sure the 7zip file has been uploaded, e.g: abc.7z and I checked it on the FTP account, it is available. However, when I click on a hyperlink of that 7z file. I can not download it from Chrome. Why it is like that?

How can I enable chrome or other browsers to download 7z from my server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try and download it? Can you `right-click..save as`? Is it only with Chrome you're having trouble with, or other browsers as well?

Comment: Check your `web.config` to make sure the client has access to the directory.

Just because the server can save the file (and, as you've confirmed, it's there) doesn't mean the _client_ has access to the file or can download it.

Comment: @keyboardP, I can right-click and save it but the content is empty. I have not tested with other browsers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is nothing specific to Google Chrome, but would happen with any web client you try - including something like `wget`.  Make sure that you have a MIME type registered for files of type `*.7z` within IIS.  Otherwise, it is likely preventing downloads of unknown types for security reasons.

Details at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965: "IIS 6.0 does not serve unknown MIME types" and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx: "Add a MIME Type (IIS 7)"

Comment: thanks. after adding the MIME Type on plesk following this guide: http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.secure-webhosting.com%2Fesup2%2Findex.php%3F_m%3Dknowledgebase%26_a%3Dpdfexport%26kbarticleid%3D296&ei=970KT-SXDtLY8QPDlYHaAQ&usg=AFQjCNG2dlN9CXkWNPaANkJyqDTtesDntQ&sig2=AqotNq4HieuG9ABgbazUlg, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the mime type of the file in your server so the server can provide it to you without any restriction.